# Duplicate jars while deploying oozie job

Tags: hadoop, oozie, jets3t

I have an oozie job which uses jets3t v 0.9 jar.
By default oozie is loading jets3t v 0.6 jar from Hadoop lib directory.
Due to this both jars are getting loaded and am getting a java verifierError.
Is there any way to stop oozie from loading certain libraries?
Or any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you keeping your jar file? Keep it in the lib folder inside workflow application folder, which will take high priority over the default hadoop version.